# Insert values in table only one column changes value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I've got a table with 2 columns,

```
GROUP    PROJECTS
10001       1
10001       2
```

First column (GROUP) stays the same value 10001.
Second column (PROJECTS) changes values 3,5,9,100, etc. (I have 400 project ID's)

What would be to correct (loop?) statement to insert all 400 PROJECTS.
I used insert, values for smaller lists.

```
INSERT INTO table (GROUP_ID, PROJECTS) VALUES (10001, 1, 10001, 2, 10001, etc, 10001, etc);
```

I have the list in Excel (if needed I can create a Temp table with all 400 project ID's)

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the correct statement for *what*?

Comment: You need to clarify the question

Comment: Sorry my english is not great. Statement is how can I insert 400 records with the same group_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically write such inserts as:

```
INSERT INTO table(GROUP_ID, PROJECTS)
    select 10001, 1 from dual union all
    select 10001, 2 from dual union all
    . . . ;
```

You should be able to generate the `select` statement pretty easily in Excel.

Comment: Sometimes its as simple as this. I'll just generate the insert statement within Excel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the project IDs exist in their own table (or you can create one from your Excel data), then yu can get the list of values from there and cross-join those with all the group IDs:

```
insert into group_projects (group_id, project_id)
select g.group_id, p.project_id
from groups g
cross join projects p
where not exists (
  select 1 from group_projects gp 
  where gp.group_id = g.group_id and gp.project_id = p.project_id
);
```

The `where not exists()` excludes all the existing pairs so you don't insert duplicates.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/122653/1)

If the groups don't have their own table then you can use the existing values from a subquery:

```
insert into group_projects (group_id, project_id)
select g.group_id, p.project_id
from (select distinct group_id from group_projects) g
cross join projects p
where not exists (
  select 1 from group_projects gp 
  where gp.group_id = g.group_id and gp.project_id = p.project_id
);
```

You could use Gordon's approach to generate the project ID list as a subquery as well, if you didn't want to create a table for those.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with what I view as a simpler and much more readable solution... create the temp table with the data from Excel, then run this-

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1
IS
SELECT project_id
 FROM temp_table
WHERE project_id IS NOT NULL;
BEGIN
FOR rec in c1
LOOP
  INSERT INTO table
  VALUES (10001, rec.project_id);
 COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Seems cleaner than one giant insert statement or something complex with joins and sub-queries. If you wanted to make sure the value doesn't already exist in "table", add that criteria to the cursor select statement, or if you have constraints on the table add an exception handler in the loop.